# show that the series is descending

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n\geq0}$ be the following series:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n}+\frac{7}{a_{n}}\right),a_{0}=3$$

`prove that the series is descending from n=1`

I'm trying to prove by induction,
I proved the base case.

for $n\geq1$ my assumption is $a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}$

but I don't know how to show the induction step.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks, and sorry if I have English mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $MA\geq MG$, we have $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+\dfrac{7}{a_n}}{2}\geq\sqrt 7$$ then $a_n\geq \sqrt 7$ for $n\geq 1$ and since $a_0=3\geq \sqrt 7$. Thus $a_n^2\geq 7$, $\forall n\geq 0$. On the other hand we have
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_n+\dfrac{7}{a_n}}{2}-a_n=\frac{\overbrace{7-a_n^2}^{\leq 0}}{\underbrace{2a_n}_{>0}}\leq 0$$
Hence $\sqrt7\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_n$, for all $n$.

Comment: wow!!!! thank you so much my friend!